# Setting ASP.NET page controls from class library assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvp

I use model view presenter approach for ASP.NET web site. The presentation part is compiled in separate class library where view contracts and presenters are defined:

```
MyPresentation assembly
IMyView
{
     DisplayText(string text);
}
MyPresenter
{
     public IMyView View { get; set; }
     public DisplayText()
     {
         string text = Generate();
         View.DisplayText(text);   
     } 
}

MyWebApplication assembly
public partial class MyForm : System.Web.UI.Page, IMyView
{
    public void DisplayText(string text)
    {
        this.myLabel.Text = text;  
    }
    ...
    protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Presenter.DisplayText(); // calls this.DisplayText()     
    }        
}
```

However after stepping out of `Presenter.DisplayText()` Text property of `myLabel` becomes null again as though no assignment were done. By all means if you replace the only line in `myButton` click event with direct setting of `myLabel` Text property everything stays assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `Generate` method return a non-null string? That looks like about the only culprit in this case. It might also explain why setting `myLabel` directly works.

To diagnose, pass a literal string to `View.DisplayText` instead of calling `Generate`.

Comment: no it does not, I substituted already to return a known string from presenter

Comment: "However after stepping out of `Presenter.DisplayText()` Text property of `myLabel` becomes null again"